# Sequentially composing two `Spec` types

Tags: haskell

Assuming

```
testValidateFEN :: Spec
testBuildBoard :: Spec
```

and the module `Test.hspec` is imported.

I am reading the following line of code:

```
hspec (testValidateFEN >> testBuildBoard)
```

My questions are:

- Does `Spec` have an instance of the `Monad` typeclass ?
- Isn't that line of code equivalent to `hspec testBuildBoard` since the first action result is discarded ?

Comment: Yes, `Spec` [does have a `Monad` instance](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/hspec-core-2.9.7/Test-Hspec-Core-Spec.html#t:SpecM). The _result_ of the first action is discarded, but its effect is still carried out.

Comment: Thank you @Fyodor Soikin. Could you explain how would you de-sugar the expression `hspec (testValidateFEN >> testBuildBoard)` ? I can't see how `hspec` is being applied to `testValidateFEN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, Spec [does have a Monad instance](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/hspec-core-2.9.7/Test-Hspec-Core-Spec.html#t:SpecM).
2. The *result* of the first action is discarded, but its effect is still carried out.

> Could you explain how would you de-sugar the expression `hspec (testValidateFEN >> testBuildBoard)`

If you look at [the definition of `Spec`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/hspec-core-2.9.7/Test-Hspec-Core-Spec.html#t:Spec), you'll see that it's a synonym for `SpecWith`, which in turn is a synonym for `SpecM`, which in turn [is a monad stack of Writer + IO wrapped in a newtype](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/hspec-core-2.9.7/Test-Hspec-Core-Spec.html#t:SpecM), with the `Monad` instance derived from the underlying stack.

So when you combine two of those with `a >> b`, that desugars into `a >>= \_ -> b` according to the [definition of `>>`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/base-4.16.4.0/src/GHC.Base.html#%3E%3E), which means "first run `a`, then take its output, throw it away, and then run `b`" - according to [the description in the `Monad` class](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.4/base-4.16.4.0/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-).

As you combine `testValidateFEN :: Spec` and `testBuildBoard :: Spec` via `>>`, you get a new value, also of type `Spec`, which, when executed, would first execute `testValidateFEN`, take its return value, throw it away, and then execute `testBuildBoard`.

Now, the crucial thing to realize here is that the important "output" of these `Spec` actions is not in their return values, but in the list of `SpecTree a` values (see definition of `SpecM`) that they accumulate via the `Writer` monad as a side-effect of their execution. Therefore, if you execute `testValidateFEN`, it will accumulate some `SpecTree a` values via the `Writer` monad, and then if you execute `testBuildBoard`, it will accumulate some more `SpecTree a` values, and the total resulting list of `[SpecTree a]` would be the combined lists that `testValidateFEN` and `testBuildBoard` would have produced on their own.